# Solution of $x'(t)=x(x(t))$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

In his book on ordinary differential equations, Arnold says that, in general, equations which contain unknown functions and their derivatives are *not* differential equations. For example, Arnold says,

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x(x(t))
$$

is not a differential equation.

How can one solve this non differential equation?

Answer (score 3):

Playing around.

If
$x'(t) = x(x(t))$,
$x''(t) 
= x'(t)x'(x(t))
= x(x(t))x(x(x(t)))
$.
By induction,
$x^{(k)}(t) 
$
involves terms
with $x(x(...x(t)...)$
nested up to
$k+1$ deep.

If
$x(t)
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n
$,
$x'(t)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_n t^{n-1}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1} t^{n}
$.

We need $x(0) = 0$
for the composition
to be defined.

Therefore
$x'(0)
=x(0)
= 0
$,
$x''(0)
= 0
$.

By induction on
$k$,
$x^{(k)}(0) 
=0
$
for all $k$.

Therefore
$x(t)$
can not be a infinite power series.

If
$x(t)
=b t^a
$,
$x'(t)
=abt^{a-1}
$
and
$x(x(t))
=b(bt^a)^a
=b^{a+1}t^{a^2}
$,
so we need
$ab=b^{a+1}$
(so
$a = b^a$ or
$b = a^{1/a})$
and
$a^2=a-1$,
so that

$a
=\frac12(1\pm\sqrt{1-4})
=\frac12(1\pm i\sqrt{3})
$.

For this,

$\begin{array}\\
t^a
&=t^{\frac12(1\pm i\sqrt{3})}\\
&=t^{1/2}e^{\pm \ln(t)\frac12( i\sqrt{3})}\\
&=t^{1/2}\left(\cos(\ln(t)\frac12( \sqrt{3}))\pm i\sin(\ln(t)\frac12( \sqrt{3}))\right)\\
\end{array}
$

From $b = a^{1/a}$
we get $b$,
but I'm not going to work that out.

That is all I can come up with
for now.

Comment: Shouldn't you have that $ab=b^{a+1}$, so that $a=b^a$ instead of $b^a=1$

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I'll fix that. Upvoted.

Comment: Didn't you already prove that $x(t) \neq bt^a$? Such an equation qualifies as a power series. You just proved it wasn't. Rather, what I believed you proved is that $x(t)$ has no meaningful Taylor series representation at 0. The Taylor series expansion of $x(t)$ is by your induction, equivalent to $0$, but the function itself is not necessarily.

Comment: No. I proved that it could not be an infinite power series - that is what requires that x(x(t)) has x(0) = 0. As you can see, if x(t) is a single term, or a finite number of terms, x(x(t)) is quite well defined.